# How can i disable to keyboard attempts while using entrybox

Tags: python, tkinter

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

```
root = tk.Tk()
yazı = ' '
root.state('zoomed')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.configure(bg='gray95')
labelsayfa = Entry(root, text='', width=28, font='Calibri 15', bg='dark gray')
c1 = Canvas(width=700, height=650, bg='dark gray')
c1.place(x=415, y=60)

def b1g():
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)), 1)

def b2g():
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)), 2)

def b3g():
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)), 3)

def b4g():
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)), 4)

def b5g():
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)), 5)

def b6g():
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)), 6)

def b7g():
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)), 7)

def b8g():
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)), 8)

def b9g():
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)), 9)

def b0g():
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)), 10)

def bacg():
    labelsayfa.delete(0, END)

def bsilg():
    labelsayfa.delete(len(labelsayfa.get()) - 1, END)

def bokg():
    pass

b1 = tk.Button(root, text='1', width=10, height=5, command=b1g)
b2 = tk.Button(root, text='2', width=10, height=5, command=b2g)
b3 = tk.Button(root, text='3', width=10, height=5, command=b3g)
b4 = tk.Button(root, text='4', width=10, height=5, command=b4g)
b5 = tk.Button(root, text='5', width=10, height=5, command=b5g)
b6 = tk.Button(root, text='6', width=10, height=5, command=b6g)
b7 = tk.Button(root, text='7', width=10, height=5, command=b7g)
b8 = tk.Button(root, text='8', width=10, height=5, command=b8g)
b9 = tk.Button(root, text='9', width=10, height=5, command=b9g)
b0 = tk.Button(root, text='0', width=10, height=5, command=b0g)
bac = tk.Button(root, text='AC', width=10, height=5, command=bacg)
bsil = tk.Button(root, text='<--', width=10, height=5, command=bsilg)
bok = tk.Button(root, text='✓', width=39, height=2, command=bokg)

def tag():
    c1.place_forget()

    labelsayfa.place(x=1200, y=100)
    bac.place(x=1200, y=160)
    b1.place(x=1300, y=160)
    b2.place(x=1400, y=160)
    b3.place(x=1200, y=260)
    b4.place(x=1300, y=260)
    b5.place(x=1400, y=260)
    b6.place(x=1200, y=360)
    b7.place(x=1300, y=360)
    b8.place(x=1400, y=360)
    b9.place(x=1200, y=460)
    b0.place(x=1300, y=460)
    bsil.place(x=1400, y=460)
    bok.place(x=1200, y=560)

tag()
root.mainloop()
```

I want to use textbox without keyboard only with buttons but i dont know how can i to do.How can i prevent the keyboard please help me i have searched all of the solitions but i couldnt find.Sorry about dots......................................................................................................

Comment: When you say _"I want to use the textbox"_ are you referring to the `Entry` widget? Tkinter doesn't have a widget named "textbox". Have you read through the documentation for the widget to learn about the `state` option?

Comment: Not textbox man i forgot i mean entry box

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off keyboard input on an entry widget by setting it's `state` parameter to `DISABLED`.

```
labelsayfa = Entry(root, text='', width=28, font='Calibri 15', bg='dark gray', state=DISABLED)
```

This will make your buttons not work as well though, so what you can do is inside your button functions, temporarily enable the entry widgets state, perform the buttons actions and then return the state back to `DISABLED` before exiting the function.

```
def b1g():
    labelsayfa.configure(state=NORMAL)
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)), 1)
    labelsayfa.configure(state=DISABLED)
```

Or to avoid repeating the same two lines in every function you can create a function wrapper also, but this would only reduce the repeated lines from 2 to 1, so it really is more of a personal preference.

For example:

```
root = tk.Tk()
yazı = ' '
root.state('zoomed')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.configure(bg='gray95')
labelsayfa = Entry(root, text='', width=28, font='Calibri 15', bg='dark gray', state=DISABLED)
c1 = Canvas(width=700, height=650, bg='dark gray')
c1.place(x=415, y=60)


def toggle_state(func):
    def wrapper():
        labelsayfa.configure(state=NORMAL)
        func()
        labelsayfa.configure(state=DISABLED)
    return wrapper

@toggle_state
def b1g():
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)), 1)


@toggle_state
def b2g():
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)), 2)

@toggle_state
def b3g():
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)), 3)

@toggle_state
def b4g():
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)), 4)

@toggle_state
def b5g():
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)), 5)

@toggle_state
def b6g():
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)), 6)

@toggle_state
def b7g():
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)), 7)

@toggle_state
def b8g():
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)), 8)

@toggle_state
def b9g():
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)), 9)

@toggle_state
def b0g():
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)), 10)

@toggle_state
def bacg():
    labelsayfa.delete(0, END)

@toggle_state
def bsilg():
    labelsayfa.delete(len(labelsayfa.get()) - 1, END)

@toggle_state
def bokg():
    pass

b1 = tk.Button(root, text='1', width=10, height=5, command=b1g)
b2 = tk.Button(root, text='2', width=10, height=5, command=b2g)
b3 = tk.Button(root, text='3', width=10, height=5, command=b3g)
b4 = tk.Button(root, text='4', width=10, height=5, command=b4g)
b5 = tk.Button(root, text='5', width=10, height=5, command=b5g)
b6 = tk.Button(root, text='6', width=10, height=5, command=b6g)
b7 = tk.Button(root, text='7', width=10, height=5, command=b7g)
b8 = tk.Button(root, text='8', width=10, height=5, command=b8g)
b9 = tk.Button(root, text='9', width=10, height=5, command=b9g)
b0 = tk.Button(root, text='0', width=10, height=5, command=b0g)
bac = tk.Button(root, text='AC', width=10, height=5, command=bacg)
bsil = tk.Button(root, text='<--', width=10, height=5, command=bsilg)
bok = tk.Button(root, text='✓', width=39, height=2, command=bokg)

def tag():
    c1.place_forget()

    labelsayfa.place(x=1200, y=100)
    bac.place(x=1200, y=160)
    b1.place(x=1300, y=160)
    b2.place(x=1400, y=160)
    b3.place(x=1200, y=260)
    b4.place(x=1300, y=260)
    b5.place(x=1400, y=260)
    b6.place(x=1200, y=360)
    b7.place(x=1300, y=360)
    b8.place(x=1400, y=360)
    b9.place(x=1200, y=460)
    b0.place(x=1300, y=460)
    bsil.place(x=1400, y=460)
    bok.place(x=1200, y=560)

tag()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the question, just add " state='readonly' "

```
Entry(root, text='', state='readonly')
```

Comment: Thank you for all answers and sorry about my english